# Custom Module Page Not Rendering Template - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm developing a custom module for a new form (nothing fancy). I've created a custom template and I'm trying to render through my controller (I've tried XML too but that didn't work) using:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('blockName');
$this->renderLayout();
```

But when I go to the page I get the site's header and footer etc. but not the content.

Here are my files:

IndexController.php

```
<?php    
    class Class_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
        public function preDispatch() {
            parent::preDispatch();
            $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('module_default');
        }
        public function indexAction() {
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('blockName');
            $this->renderLayout();
        }
        public function postAction() {
            $_post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            // form fields
            $_name        = $_post['name'];
            $_to          = $_post['email'];
            $_phoneModel  = $_post['phone_model'];
            $_phoneNumber = $_post['phone_number'];
            $_issue       = $_post['issue'];
            // email set up
            $_subject = 'A Subject';
            $_message = 'Hey, ' . $_name . 'said that there phone (' . $_phoneModel . ') has the following issue:';
            $_message .= $_issue;
            $_message .= 'Their number is ' . $_phoneNumber;
            // magento mail set up
            $_mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
            $_mail->setToName($_name);
            $_mail->setToEmail($_to);
            $_mail->setBody($_message);
            $_mail->setSubject($_subject);
            // send mail
            try {
                $_mail->send();
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess('Email sent successfully!');
                $this->_redirect('');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send message. Please try again later.');
                $this->_redirect('');
            }
        }
    }
```

My config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Class_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Class_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <module>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Class_Module</module>
                    <frontName>module</frontName>
                </args>
            </module>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <!-- my attempt with xml -->
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <module module="page" translate="label">
                    <label>Label</label>
                    <template>contacts/template.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>block_form_default</layout_handle>
                </module>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

and my template.phtml file:

```
<div id="messages_product_view">
    <?= $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
</div>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<form id="formId" method="POST" action="<?= $this->getFormAction() ?>">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <ul class="fields">
            <li class="field">
                <label for="name" class="required">Name</label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="John/Jane Doe" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="field">
                <label for="email" class="required">Email Address</label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.co.uk" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="field">
                <label for="phone_model" class="required">Phone Model</label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="name" name="phone_model" placeholder="HTC Desire 310" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="field">
                <label for="phone_number" class="required">Phone Number</label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="number" name="phone_number" placeholder="0123456789" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="field">
                <label for="issue" class="required">Issue</label>
                <textarea name="issue"></textarea>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="Submit" class="button">
            <span>
                <span>Submit</span>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    //<![CDATA
        var form = new VarienForm('formId', true);
    //]]>
</script>
```

I've been scratchin' my head for hours. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Weird way of defining layout (in config.xml). I've never seen something like this :D Maybe try define layout in standard way with separate xml file, here http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/07/create-your-first-magento-module.html You have tutorial. Since 5 years I make modules like that and it work :)

Comment: I hadn't done it that way (link to tutorial) instead I found a cool post - if I find it I'll paste a link - that shows how you can render it from the controller using toHtml()

Comment: Yep you can make it in thousand different methods :) but method from my link is a good way, good programmers/projects always use separate layout files :)